# How to pass data between two different angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here is my requirement

I have two Angular web application `App1` & App2. Here in `App1` i am creating an token object (it can be a string too).

I want to open by replacing the url from `App1` with the URl of `App2`(No new window should open, it should open the App2 url on same address bar)

Here i have tried the below approach it's not working so far

This code in "App1" by pressing the button i am triggering `App2`

The Code written in `App1`

```
goToNextPage(){



var domain = 'http://localhost:1338/';
// //create popup window

var myPopup = window.open(domain,"_self"); 



// //periodical message sender
 setInterval(function(){
    var message = 'current time: ' + (new Date().getTime());
    console.log('blog.local:  sending message:  ' + message);
   myPopup.postMessage(message,domain);
    //send the message and target URI

 },2000);


 window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {


    if(event.origin !== 'http://localhost:1337/') return;
    console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
 },false);


  }
```

In App2 i am using below code to retrieve the data.

```
constructor(public cookieService:CookieService){




//     //respond to events
 window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
  debugger

//   //
     if(event.origin == 'http://localhost:1337/') return;
  console.log('message received:  ' + event.data,event);
  alert('message received:  ' + JSON.stringify(event.data))
//  //event.source.postMessage('holla back youngin!',event.origin);
 },false);
  }
```

Here in am getting the `event.data` is `undefined`

Any idea what could be the solution for this

Comment: Unless you have both running concurrently you won't be able to send messages between the two. If you want to store information like this perhaps look into `localstorage`

Comment: Or simply use the URL to pass data. This is not going to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a server side shared api or pass data on the url with a query string. Things like cookies, session storage and local storage could work if the two apps are running on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Angular 2+ you can use cookies
Step -1 install `npm install ngx-cookie-service` for both the apps or can install globally
Step 2 .

App1 - > app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App1 - app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-first-project';

  constructor(public cookieService:CookieService){

  }

  goToNextPage(){

  this.cookieService.set("my-key","yourkey")
  }

}
```

App2 - app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App2 - app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-second-project';

  constructor(public cookieService:CookieService){

    alert(this.cookieService.get("my-key"))

  }
}
```

Very simple .. But you can look also other ways like other has mentioned.

Comment: With this you'll enter in the world of security violation!